# javascript drag and drop image as a number variable

Tags: javascript

I am using an open-source project that i would like to edit and evolve into a game.

It uses javascript drag and drop which creates a pile of shuffled cards using numbers which are then displayed randomly using math.random.

I am looking for away to use different images for each number.

is there away to have

```
numbers[1] = image url;
numbers[2] = image url;
```

or is there away to use images instead of the numbers within the

```
var numbers =['<img src="../card-one.png">', '<img src="../card-two.png">']
```

Currently the drag and drop function wont be recognised if i just added images as above.

```
var numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ];
  numbers.sort( function() { return Math.random() - .5 } );

  for ( var i=0; i<10; i++ ) {
    $('<div>' + numbers[i] + '</div>').data( 'number', numbers[i] ).attr( 'id', 'card'+numbers[i] ).appendTo( '#cardPile' ).draggable( {
      containment: '#content',
      stack: '#cardPile div',
      cursor: 'move',
      revert: true
    } );
  }

  // Create the card slots
  var words = [ 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten' ];
  for ( var i=1; i<=10; i++ ) {
    $('<div>' + words[i-1] + '</div>').data( 'number', i ).appendTo( '#cardSlots' ).droppable( {
      accept: '#cardPile div',
      hoverClass: 'hovered',
      drop: handleCardDrop
    } );
  }

}
```

Check out this fiddle to get an idea of what this current script does

http://jsfiddle.net/Vp89Z/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
var imag = new Image();
imag.src = 'src-to-image';
number[1] = imag;
```

Comment: It displays the image but it doesn't add it to the number 1, it seems to add the image to any random number, is that something to do with the return Math.random

Comment: @DaisyOopsy Do you know that the first item in an array is the 0th?